# Efficient sort-by function

Tags: java, performance, sorting

For a Java project I'm working on, I need to make a sort-by method, which sorts a list using a mapping function. The most obvious solution is to use the built-in `Collections.sort()` method:

```
static <D, R extends Comparable> void sortBy(List<D> list, Function<D, R> function) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<D>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(D d1, D d2) {
            return function.apply(d1).compareTo(function.apply(d2));
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that this calls the function on each element many times (I think about 2 log N). Furthermore, the function is likely to be slow, with each invocation taking at least a few milliseconds, possibly much longer. I'd like a more efficient algorithm which calls the function as few times as possible.

I've considered applying each function at the beginning, and then sorting the mapped list, but I don't see how to get back to the original list:

```
static <D, R extends Comparable> void sortBy(List<D> list, Function<D, R> function) {
    List<R> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (D d : list){
        newList.add(function.apply(d));
    }
    Collections.sort(newList);

    // now what?
}
```

(Note that the function is pure, i.e. each input yields the same output, with no side effects.)

Comment: I suggest you to use memoization and store the result of `function.apply(d)` to improve the comparison. Apart of this, measure the time using a profiler or a framework like caliper or jmh before stating that this is a bottleneck in your app.

Comment: list of data -> list of tuples with data and applied_function_result -> sort it by this result -> strip back to list of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in comments, you can sort a list of some kind of tuple that will hold the original value and the computed one. Then you build a new list by extracting the original values in sorted order.
This solution creates temporary objects (the tuples), but should be efficient if the mapping function is expensive. Of course, this needs to be measured...

```
static <D, R extends Comparable> List<D> sortBy(List<D> list, Function<D, R> function) {
    // Build the list of pairs
    List<Pair<D,R>> newList = list.stream()
            .map(d -> new Pair<>(d, function.apply(d)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Sort the list of pairs on second member, which is the computed one
    Collections.sort(newList, new Comparator<Pair<D,R>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<D, R> p1, Pair<D, R> p2) {
            return p1.second.compareTo(p2.second);
        }
    });

    // extract the first member of pair, which is the original value 
    return newList.stream().map(p -> p.first).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Given a simple class `Pair<U, V>` like:

```
public final class Pair<U,V> {
   public final U first;
   public final V second;
   public Pair(U u, V v) {
      this.first = u;
      this.second = v;
   }
   public String toString() {
      return "["+first+","+second+"]";
   }
}
```

Then:

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("blah", "foo", "bar", "hello world", "bye bye", "fizz", "buzz");

List<String> sortedDataByLength = sortBy(data, new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String t) {
        return t.length();
    }});
System.out.println(sortedDataByLength);
```

Yields:

```
[foo, bar, blah, fizz, buzz, bye bye, hello world]
```

Comment: You could use `Stream#sorted(...)` to implement `sortedBy(...)` in a single stream pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `R` simply containing the result, implement it so that it is a composite object that contains a reference to its corresponding `D` as well. Then you can sort by `R` and extract `D` out of each `R` element in the sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement simple memoization using the new Java 8 `Map#computeIfAbsent(...)` method:

```
  static <D, R extends Comparable<? super R>> void sortBy(List<D> list, Function<D, R> function) {
    Map<D, R> memo = new HashMap<>();
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<D>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(D d1, D d2) {
        R r1 = memo.computeIfAbsent(d1, function);
        R r2 = memo.computeIfAbsent(d2, function);
        return r1.compareTo(r2);
      }
    });
  }
```